# Signal current cannot be synthesized, bad synchronous description

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I have a error while Synthesize this code in Xillinx. This error is:

> Analyzing Entity  in library  (Architecture ).
>   ERROR:Xst:827 - "C:/Xilinx92i/Parking/Parking.vhd" line 43: Signal current cannot be synthesized, bad synchronous description.

```
entity Parking is port(
    A, B ,reset: in std_logic;
    Capacity : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end Parking;

architecture Behavioral of Parking is
    type state is (NoChange, Aseen, Bseen, ABseen, BAseen, Input, Output, Din, Dout);
    signal current, nxt : state ;
    signal counter : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := "00000000";
begin

    p1: process(A, B, reset)
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            current <= Nochange;
        end if;

        if(A'event and A='1') then
            current <= nxt;
        end if;

        if(A'event and A='0') then
            current <= nxt;
        end if;

        if(B'event and B='1') then
            current <= nxt;
        end if;

        if(B'event and B='0') then
            current <= nxt;
        end if;
    end process;

    p2: process(current, A, B)
    begin
        case current is
            when Aseen =>
                if B='1' then
                    nxt <= ABseen;
                else
                    nxt <= NoChange;
                end if;

            when others =>
                nxt <= Nochange;
        end case;
    end process;

    Capacity <= counter;

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error 'bad synchronous description' usually means that you have described a register (clocked element) that does not exist in the hardware.

In the case of your code, you have:

```
if(A'event and A='1') then
   current <= nxt;
end if;

if(A'event and A='0') then
    current <= nxt;
end if;

-- etc
```

inside one process. Synchronous synthesisable processes will typically only have one clock, because there is no element in a real silicon device like an FPGA that can respond to events on two different clocks. A process like the one you are trying to implement would typically look something more like this:

```
process (clk)   
begin
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
        if (a = '1') then
            current <= nxt;
        elsif (a = '0') then
            current <= nxt;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Implementing it this way requires that you have:

1. A clock in your system
2. Inputs that meet setup/hold times relative to this clock

#### Side note

If you don't have a meaningful name for a process, you don't have to give it one at all. `process (clk)` is just as valid as `p1 : process(clk)`.

Comment: In this program, I'm going to have two signals A and B at the role of clock.

Comment: If you need to have multiple clock signals, each clock will need to have its own process, setting/clearing signals that can then be monitored by some other process. You can't do what you have written in your code.

Comment: @mahsa93 Are A and B really clocks or are they clock enables? You can also not describe asynchronous resets with lower priority than clock edges. Can you draw us a waveform with A,B and current?