# Signal temp2 cannot be synthesized, bad synchronous description

Tags: vhdl

```
entity timer is
    Port ( click : in  STD_LOGIC;
           clear : out  STD_LOGIC;
           t_unlock : out  STD_LOGIC);
end timer;

architecture Behavioral of timer is
    signal temp2 : integer range 0 to 20 := 0;
begin
    process
    begin
        if rising_edge(click) then
            temp2<=0;
            clear<='0';
            t_unlock<='0';
        else
            temp2<=temp2+1 after 15 ns;
        end if;
        if temp2=6 then
            clear<='1';
        elsif temp2=20 then
            t_unlock<='1';
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

I have writted this code.And the complier say:

```
Signal temp2 cannot be synthesized, bad synchronous description. The description style you are using to describe a synchronous element (register, memory, etc.) is not supported in the current software release.
```

I have searched on stackoverflow.They say [The error 'bad synchronous description' usually means that you have described a register (clocked element) that does not exist in the hardware.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377494/signal-current-cannot-be-synthesized-bad-synchronous-description)But I don't know how to solve my problem.

Comment: Add the signals click & temp2 to the sensitivity list, and remove the <code> after 15 ns </code>. What are you using to synthesize?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The VHDL has to follow some synthesis tool specific coding guidelines, for the tool to be able to translate the VHDL code into the FPGA implementation.  For implementation to a flip-flop with asynchronous reset, the style can be:

```
process (clk, rst) is
begin
  -- Clock
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    ... -- Update at clock
  end if;
  -- Asynchronous reset
  if rst = '1' then
    ... -- Update at reset
  end if;
end process;
```

In the case of your code it looks like you are not using the asynchronous reset, thus the template may be reduced to:

```
process (clk) is
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    ... -- Update at clock
  end if;
end process;
```

The exercise is now for you to fit your code into that template, and unfortunately it is pretty hard to determine the exact intention based on the provided code.

Comment: Surely it should be of the form; if reset then --- elsif rising_edge(clk) then--- end if. Otherwise you'll throw a multiple drivers error?

Comment: No, the `if rst = '1' then ... elsif rising_edge(clk) then ... end if;` form means that signals not driven by the reset part must be held stable at reset, even at rising clk, since the clock part is then never reached.   This required hold/latch operation, which is probably not the intention.  With the `if rising_edge(clk) then ... end if;  if rst = '1' then ... end if;` form the signal not updated by reset can just be updated by clock, which matches ordinary flip-flop operation.  There will not be a multiple driver, since all are in the same process.

Comment: Brilliant thanks - by coincidence its almost exactly the same as a problem I'm working on !

Comment: @MortenZilmer both forms result in the same hardware... The difference you mention is conceptual, but not real. No hold/latch will be inferred.

Comment: is it true what @JHBonarius mentioned? Will it not infer a latch but an actual flipflip with async reset even if you do the "if rst .. elsif" dance? Or does it depend on the cleverness of the synthesis tool, with the code in answer being more idiomatic, hence working on more synthesis tools?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb The proper construct is described in the synthesis tool user guide, HDL coding guidelines. Of course it is possible to infer a latch if you do not follow the proper guidelines. But `process(clk,rst) begin if rst [...] elsif rising_edge(clk) [...]` is the prescribed way for most FPGA synthesis tools. Although most manufacturers now prescribe synchronous reset. Or even reset-less design for high-speed applications.

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems to mix concepts of HDL and "software" languages. I'm not sure what it's supposed to do, but I would refactor it into the code below

```
architecture Behavioral of timer is
    constant COUNTER_VALUE_TO_REACH_15ns : integer := <some value>;

    signal temp2   : integer range 0 to 20 := 0;
    signal divider : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
    process
    begin
        -- Everything happens when the clock ticks, except for reset
        if rising_edge(click) then
            temp2    <= 0;
            clear    <= '0';
            t_unlock <= '0';

            -- Count how many cycles until we need to increment temp2
            if divider = COUNTER_VALUE_TO_REACH_15ns then
                temp2   <= temp2 + 1;
                divider <= (others => '0'); -- Reset the counter when we reach the required amount of time
            else
                divider <= divider + 1;
            end if;

            if temp2 = 6 then
                clear <= '1';
            elsif temp2 = 20 then
                t_unlock <= '1';
            end if;

        else
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: This code contains many errors. I suggested an edit, but it was rejected.