# VHDL inferring latches

Tags: vhdl

I have a question on VHDL. The code below is for a +/- 2 degree thermostat it works and simulates well, but I have a few unexplained warnings one of them in particular is really bugging me.

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.all, IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
ENTITY thermo IS
    PORT    (
            Tset, Tact: in integer;
            Heaton:     out std_logic
            );
 END ENTITY thermo;

 ARCHITECTURE sequential OF thermo IS
BEGIN
    PROCESS (Tact, Tset) IS
    VARIABLE ONOFF: std_logic;
    BEGIN
        IF Tact <= (Tset - 2) then
            ONOFF := '1';
        ELSIF Tact >= (Tset + 2) then
            ONOFF := '0';
        ELSE ONOFF := ONOFF;
        END IF;
        Heaton <= ONOFF;
END PROCESS;
END ARCHITECTURE sequential;
```

The warning message thats bugging me is this:

> Warning (10631): VHDL Process Statement warning at thermo.vhd(19): inferring latch(es) for signal or variable "ONOFF", which holds its previous value in one or more paths through the process<

Like I said the code works ok on ModelSim but this makes me think i am going about things the wrong way. Any suggestions ?
Thanks
Danny J

Comment: You are explicitly calling for a latch. If that's what you want, don't worry about the warning. It's  a warning because it's not best practice (e.g. leading to unreliable timings in large designs) but it's not an error and should be OK in such a simple design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is specified to hold the current value of `ONOFF` with the line:

```
ELSE ONOFF := ONOFF;
```

Holding the value based on combinatorial inputs, like `Tact` and `Tset`, requires a latch, as reported in the warning, since usually latches means that the designer created code with an unintentional side effect.

If you want to keep the state, then consider making a clocked process instead; a template is provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34067908/2352082).

If you want a combinatorial output, then get ridge of the internal `ONOFF` process variable, and make sure that an explicit value is assigned in all branches of the `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I have created a clock version already which like you say works fine. I was trying to express a combinational logic description but I need to reduce the Tset and Tact bit size other wise the IF statement becomes to big.

Comment: The variable `ONOFF` also holds its current value, if the line `ELSE ONOFF := ONOFF;` is removed and neither the set or reset condition is true.

Comment: "If you want a combinatorial output, then get ridge of the internal ONOFF process variable, and make sure that an explicit value is assigned in all branches of the if statement." -- will this change anything with respective to the resulting synthesis or is this just to clarify to the synthesis tool that a latch is intended?

Comment: See withdrawn IEEE Std 1076.6-2004  RTL Synthesis 6.2.1.1 Level-sensitive storage from process with sensitivity list  "By default, the effect of an identity assignment of the signal (or variable) shall be as though the assignment was not present." the treated as not present identity assignment doesn't overcome  "A level-sensitive storage element shall be modeled for a signal (or variable) when all the following apply: ... c) There are executions of the process that do not execute an explicit assignment (via an assignment statement) to the signal (or variable)."

Answer (score 2):

You have described a [SR latch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#Simple_set-reset_latches) for the signal `ONOFF`. This works fine in simulation but makes problems in FPGAs as well as digital circuits build from discrete components.

Your latch is set when the expression `Tact <= (Tset - 2)` is true. Now image a point in time, when the latch is currently in state `'0'` and `Tact = Tset`. Thus, the latch keps `'0'` as expected. This works as long as `Tact` is not changing. Now let the temperature fall to `Tact = Tset-1`. According to the above expression, the latch should keep in state `'0'`. But, this cannot be ensured in real hardware because the expression is not evaluated at once. Instead the multi-bit comparator for the `<=` operator may produce a [glitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glitch#Electronics_glitch) because the comparator itself is composed of several gates. If one of these gates is switching faster than another one, there might be an intermediate result, where the expression is true and, thus, your latch becomes `'1'`.

To notify the designer, that latches are susceptible for glitches, the synthesis compiler issues the above warning. To circumvent this problem, the FPGA offers [D flip-flops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#D_flip-flop) which state is only updated on clock-edges. The timing analyzer of the FPGA toolchain ensures, that the evaluation of the above expression is completed before the next rising (or falling) clock-edge. So, the designer has not to worry about glitches!

You can describe a clock-edge triggered SR flip-flop in VHDL which is then mapped to the D flip-flop of the FPGA by the synthesis tool. The code style is as follows:

```
signal Q : std_logic; -- declare signal in the declarations part of the architecture
...
process(clock)
begin
  if rising_edge(clock) then -- flip-flop triggered at the rising clock edge
    if set_expression then
      Q <= '1';
    elsif reset_expression then
      Q <= '0';
    end if;
  end if;
end if;
```

The state of the SR flip-flop is saved in the signal `Q`. I have used a signal instead of an variable here, because variables are harder to debug. (I recommend to use signals as often as possible.) In this code example, if both `set_expression` and `reset_expression` are both true, then the "set" takes precedence. (Can be flipped if required.) If none of the expressions is true, then the old state is saved as required by a flip-flop.