# flip-flop does not hold value until its clock NOT edge condition

Tags: vhdl

I tried to create a flip-flop which has a reset-enable and a synchronous data load. It works fine in VHDL simulation, but when I try to synthesize it in ISE it gives me the following error:

> Line 24: statement is not synthesizable since it does not hold its value under NOT(clock-edge) condition

Here is the code:

```
library ieee;  
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity D_FF is
port (D: in std_logic;
      clk: in std_logic;
      reset_enable: in std_logic;
      reset: in std_logic;
      Q: out std_logic:='0'
); 
end D_FF;    

architecture a1 of D_FF is
begin
  proc: process (D,clk,reset,reset_enable)
  begin
    if (reset_enable='1') then 
      if (reset='1') then
        q<='0';
      end if;
    end if;
    if (clk'event and clk='1') then -- Line 24
      q<=d; 
    end if; 
  end process proc;
end a1;
```

How can I fix this error in order to make the code synthesizable and also equivalent to the one I wrote?

Comment: Your two if statements assigning `q` describe sequential logic, one a latch and the other a register. Combine them into one if statement with an asynchronous part - `if` reset_condition ... followed by `elsif`clock_event_condition.... . Xilinx avoids showing asynchronous reset/set coding examples in their synthesis user guides. The use discouraged as blocking some types of optimization. Also see IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 IEEE Standard for VHDL Register Transfer Level (RTL) Synthesis (withdrawn). You don't need D in the sensitivity list.

Comment: Your clocked processes needs to look like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34067908/4090959. Also do not `use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;` or `use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;`.

Comment: what is a `reset_enable`? Preferably don't use this: you add logic in the asynchronous domain, which could end up in timing closure issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To point you into the right direction: What happens when there is a reset AND a clk edge at the same time?

A solution:

```
if (reset = '1' and reset_enable = '1') then
    q <= '0';
elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then
    q <= d;
end if;
```